# How to import data from a csv file into a java object arraylist with the Jackson library? please

Tags: java, csv, import, jackson

The object in question:

```
public class DataSupplyPoint {

    private String date;
    private double value;
    private SupplyPoint supplyPoint;

    public DataSupplyPoint(String date, double value, SupplyPoint supplyPoint) {
        super();
        this.date = date;
        this.value = value;
        this.supplyPoint = supplyPoint;
    }
```

Example of my csv file:

```
supplyPoint,date,value
0123456678,2021-03-10,2412.1999
0123456678,2021-06-10,3412.1999
0123456678,2021-09-10,4412.1999
0123456678,2021-12-10,5412.1999
0123456678,2021-03-10,2412.1999
0123456678,2021-06-10,3412.1999
0123456678,2021-09-10,4412.1999
0123456678,2021-12-10,5412.1999
```

What I tried to do:

```
public ArrayList<DataSupplyPoint> importDataSupplyPointInCSV(String fileName) {
    CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
    CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader();
    ObjectReader oReader = csvMapper.readerFor(DataSupplyPoint.class).with(schema);
    ArrayList<DataSupplyPoint> dataSupplyPointList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    try(Reader reader = new FileReader(fileName + ".csv")) {
        MappingIterator<DataSupplyPoint> mi = oReader.readValues(reader);
        
        while (mi.hasNext()) {
            DataSupplyPoint current = mi.next();
            dataSupplyPointList.add(current);
        }
        return dataSupplyPointList;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return dataSupplyPointList;
    }       
}
```

It makes me make this mistake:

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `user.SupplyPoint` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('012345678912345678’)'''

This is my first post, I promise to improve ahah

Comment: Have you tried doing a web search for "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of"?  I am sure if you put that into your preferred search engine you will find some clues as to what you are doing wrong.  You might even find a solution if you search on stack overflow :)

Comment: Welcome to this site. The preferred way here to show code is to use text, not images.
This enables people to copy & paste it and reproduce your problem.more easily.

Comment: Yes, I have @Gavin. If I finally decided to do a post, it's because I didn't find a solution to it and that I looked for a solution beforehand :/ I feel lousy right now

Comment: Thank you @ThomasFritsch :)

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of class `DataSupplyPoint` Jackson does not know
which CSV column corresponds to which constructor parameter.
Jackson cannot figure this out from the Java names of the constructor parameters.
Therefore you need to tell it explicitly by annotating the parameters
with `@JsonProperty`:

```
public DataSupplyPoint(@JsonProperty("date") String date,
                       @JsonProperty("value") double value,
                       @JsonProperty("supplyPoint") SupplyPoint supplyPoint) {
    super();
    this.date = date;
    this.value = value;
    this.supplyPoint = supplyPoint;
}
```

See also the [javadoc of `@JsonCreator`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html):

> NOTE: when annotating creator methods (constructors, factory methods), method must either be:
>
> - Single-argument constructor/factory method without `JsonProperty` annotation for the argument:
>   if so, this is so-called "delegate creator", in which case Jackson first binds
>   JSON into type of the argument, and then calls creator. This is often used in conjunction
>   with `JsonValue` (used for serialization).
> - Constructor/factory method where **every argument** is annotated with either `JsonProperty`
>   or `JacksonInject`, to indicate name of property to bind to